# To Display Alert message

Tags: node.js

I have created a register api using nodejs . When I click the register button I am rendering back to register form but now I also want to give a alert message that Registration successful if it is successfully registered else a fail response

Answer (score 0):

you can make your request like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/url/is/here",
    method: "POST",
    data : {
        data : "what you want to send",
        put : "them here"
    },
    cache : false,
    success : function (data) {
        // data is the object that you send form the server by 
        // res.jsonp();
        // here data = {success : true}
        // validate it
        if(data['success']){
            alert("message you want to show");
        }
    },
    error : function () {
        // some error handling part
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
    }
});
```